# How can I make the onClose property work in case of escapeKeyDown and backdropClick in MUI <Modal> component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui, modal-dialog, react-props

I have a standart handleClose func

```
const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false)
    router.back()
  }
```

Which I pass to onClose

```
<Modal
      open={visible}
      onClose={handleClose} />
```

I also have a hack for onClose described in the interface

```
export interface ModalProps
  onClose?: {
    bivarianceHack(event: {}, reason: 'backdropClick' | 'escapeKeyDown'): void;
  }['bivarianceHack'];
}
```

However, in the case of the escape button, it works, but when click on backdrop, nothing happens

I tried using onBackdropClick, as well as disableBackdropClick={false}, which is considered obsolete, but this also does not help